# How to create Dataflow pipeline in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-ai-platform

How to create a Dataflow pipeline that sends batched requests to the hosted AI model (in GCP AI platform), to retrieve probability predictions, and write the results to a table in BigQuery.

Any relative dataflow flex template would also be helpful.

The dataflow desired is similar to as

[Reading the full kaggle dataset (6M+) form GCS bucket and publish some random mock data in PubSub topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IH9F.png)

[Full DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UonI0.png)

[Predict Transform with 500KB payload / request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHleq.png)

The sample code i tried to follow is from [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/df-ml-anomaly-detection) Github repo.

I have tried consulting the guides from the GCP such as

1. https://cloud.google.com/architecture/detecting-anomalies-in-financial-transactions

But the public image of a Dataflow flex template (
gcr.io/cloud-solutions-images/df-ml-finserv-anomaly-detection:latest) used to trigger this pipeline is no longer available.

Comment: That image can be rebuilt from the sources. There are some instructions here https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates and the repository itself https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/df-ml-anomaly-detection has instructions.